# How can I update current value of a sequence in JavaDB Derby database?

Tags: java, database, sequence, derby, javadb

I'm using a sequence to generate custom id for a database table, but at first, I have to run some `INSERT` statements with rows which already have id in this format. So, I need to update the current value of sequence to ensure there are no duplicate ids the next time that values ​​are inserted from the application.

> For example, I have a table whose id is generated using a sequence that start with 1, but I have to do an initial configuration that involves running some `INSERT` statements with a preestablished id.
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable (id, ...) VALUES (A001, ...);
> INSERT INTO mytable (id, ...) VALUES (A002, ...);
> INSERT INTO mytable (id, ...) VALUES (A003, ...);
> ...
> INSERT INTO mytable (id, ...) VALUES (A082, ...);
> ```
>
> After that, current value of sequence need to be updated to 82, so that when `NEXT VALUE FOR` expression is called to get id for insert a new row, it returns the value 83.

I know in PostgreSQL I can use the next sentence for that purpose, but I can't find anything like that in Derby official documentation.

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('sequence_name', 82, true);
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can specify `START WITH` when you create the sequence: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefsqljcreatesequence.html

Comment: Yes, I could drop the sequence and create it again with `START WITH` option, but that's not the idea.